# ExtJS 4.2.1 - Building Custom Themes - Build Failure Error: com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: Unknown image type 0

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

When I follow the steps on the Sencha Docs URL: 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/theming

I get to the step titled "Generating an Application for Testing the Theme" and I do a **sencha app build** 
I get the following error:

```
[INF] Capture complete
[INF]      [echo] Slicing theme images to C:\codebase\ExtJSTemplate\my-workspace
/build/ThemeDemoApp/production/resources
[INF] Including theme package my-custom-theme for app.theme=my-custom-theme buil
d
[INF] Slicing images...
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: Unknown image type 0
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 1 minute 2 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\codebase\ExtJSTemplate\my-workspace\theme-demo-app\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml
:478: com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: Unknown image type 0
```

This is on a Windows XP machine. I did the same exact setup steps on my Macbook Pro and it works with no problems. For some reason on my Windows machine, I am stuck on this error.

I verified that I have the same JAVA, Ruby, and Sencha CMD versions installed on both machines.

Any ideas?

I am using:
java version "1.6.0_11"
Sencha Cmd v3.1.2.342
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i386-mingw32]

Comment: I see this thread on Sencha forums talking about possible problems with older Java versions: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?262520-Unknown-image-type-when-building-theme-package

Comment: Slightly different issue on that thread. Still experiencing this issue.